# Android Frame by Frame Animation problem on elements in a CursorAdapter

Tags: java, android, animation

I am having trouble applying an animation to a View. I am trying to load the animation from inside the constructor of a CursorAdapter, so I can set it later assign it to certain children in the list.

In the constructor I have :

```
shineAnimation = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(ctx, R.anim.news_list_item_shine);
```

the animation is in my res/anim dir

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<animation-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:oneshot="true">
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/shine1" android:duration="200" />
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/shine2" android:duration="200" />
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/shine3" android:duration="200" />
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/shine4" android:duration="200" />
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/shine5" android:duration="200" />
</animation-list>
```

I'm getting an exception :
    Unknown animation name: animation-list

Help would be much appreciated

Thanks
S

Answer (score 2):

I don't think you load `AnimationDrawables` via `AnimationUtils`. `AnimationDrawable` is a `Drawable` more than it is an `Animation`. Try [this sample code](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/graphics/2d-graphics.html#frame-animation) from the SDK guide.

```
  ImageView rocketImage = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.rocket_image);
  rocketImage.setBackgroundResource(R.anim.rocket_thrust);
  rocketAnimation = (AnimationDrawable) rocketImage.getBackground();
```

Comment: Hi,

Thanks for answering, that is you again isn't it Mark :)

The reason I didn't try and use the setBackgroundResource is that I suspect that will cause the animation to run as the background fo my view. I suppose I could get around this by placing an empty ImageView in front of all the other elements and use setBackgroundResource() on that?

Comment: You probably do not have to use it as a background, but I think you have to use it as a Drawable, not as an Animation. Try setImageResource() on your ImageView instead of setBackgroundResource(), or something.